# How to list all processes by non-root users?

Tags: linux, process, ps

I want to see a list of processes similar to what `ps aux` outputs but not show any `root` processes.

Answer (score 4):

```
ps u $(pgrep -vu root)
```

Explanation

- `pgrep` - to search for processes, returning their numeric PIDs
- `-v` - inverse of filter
- `-u root` - filter processes owned by root
- `$(…)` - substitution
- `ps u …` - show list view of a series of processes

*Update:* The original solution is practically equivalent to another one, below, just uses `xargs` instead of `$(…)`:

```
pgrep -vu root | xargs ps u
```

Comment: +1 (assuming `$IFS` contains its default value). Or `ps aux | awk '$1 != "root"'` (assuming no usernames contain blanks characters).

Answer (score 1):

This works in Fedora 35 (ps from procps-ng 3.3.17):

```
ps u -N -u root
```

Personally I always use the `f` flag. Makes reading the output easier: `ps fu -N -u root`

Answer (score 1):

This works on my Debian systems, and my macOS 10.15. It may be a bit of *overkill* for this requirement, but it's fairly *adaptable* to other requirements:

```
ps -eo pid,stat,ruser,command | awk '{ if ($3 != "root") print $0;}'
  PID STAT RUSER    COMMAND
  312 Ssl  systemd+ /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
  349 Ss   avahi    avahi-daemon: running [raspberrypi4b.local]
  359 Ss   nobody   /usr/sbin/thd --triggers /etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d/ --socket /run/thd.socket --user nobody --deviceglob /dev/input/event*
  365 Ss   message+ /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
  393 S    avahi    avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  620 Ss   vnstat   /usr/sbin/vnstatd -n
  910 Ss   Debian-+ /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
 2193 R+   pi       ps -eo pid,stat,ruser,command
 2194 S+   pi       awk { if ($3 != "root") print $0;}

# alternatively, for a more compact output: 

ps -eo pid,ruser | awk '{ if ($2 != "root") print $0;}'
  PID RUSER
  312 systemd-timesync
  349 avahi
  359 nobody
  365 messagebus
  393 avahi
  620 vnstat
  910 Debian-exim
 2204 pi
 2205 pi
```

*<sup>note: listings above are not complete; culled for brevity</sup>*

Summary:

**`ps -e`** shows every process on the system using *standard syntax* (`aux` is *BSD syntax*)

**`ps -eo`** the `-o` option is one of several listed in the `OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL` section of `man ps` that may be used to choose what information is displayed by `ps`. *Why clutter your output with stuff you don't care about*? If you want it all, `ps -e` is all you need.

**`ps -eo pid,stat,ruser,command`** the `-o` option allows selection of output parameters by using one or more of the *keywords* listed in `man ps` under the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section. In this **example**, `ps` lists all PIDs, process states, real user IDs and the `command` that spawned them. Once again, see the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section of `man ps` for the complete list of keywords.

The pipe to `awk` simply filters all `root` user processes, and of course is easily modified to filter on other fields in the `ps` output.

Comment: `grep -v root` would filter out some additional processes if they contain the string `root`.  Example, an non-root user running `/usr/bin/frootyloops` would be filtered out.

Similar concern for `grep -v grep`.  If a non-root user is running an expensive grep, such as `grep -rl foo /`, the filter would hide such a process.

Comment: @JoshuaHuber: Yes it would; `awk` would be a better solution than `grep`.